# VUE build for production does not apply CSS

Tags: vue.js, frontend, yarnpkg, npm-build

I have purchased [this VUE template](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-material-dashboard-pro/?_ga=2.40884962.151856726.1622746622-387188167.1622557245#/dashboard). From its documentation, if I run `npm run install && npm run dev`. It looks correct [image: output when "npm run serve"]

When I execute `npm run build` to get my production ready project. As you can see, it does not look the same:
[image]

I have checked the css links inside of the generated HTML, and there is only one pointing to "a file". I believe is the right one...(?)

Here is `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './' : './',
  outputDir: 'dist',
  assetsDir: 'app',
  indexPath: 'index.html',
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  },

}
```

My `env.production` looks like:

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_TITLE=My Base Front End
```

1. What am I missing on the config file?

Comment: Open the browser console and check for errors. It has to be a path issue. Check if the browser is giving errors about loading files in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code for tag `stylesheet_pack_tag` in your layout file :

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I can recall similar issue from past experience.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, in the local env it was applying but not in production.

In my case the problem was that the lang of the style was not specified as scss, modifying it to

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
```

fixed the issue (although it's still odd it worked in the local env)